# Gmail addon - compose trigger select action without Card / UI

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

Following [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/gmail/extending-compose-ui), I could create a new icon in Gmail compose UI which opens a Card, let's the user choose a photo, and inserts it into the email.
How can I directly insert the image once the icon is clicked on? This is going to be a frequent action and I don't want to require my user to deal with the UI every time. Is there any way to directly set a function returning `newUpdateDraftBodyAction` in my composeTrigger.selectActions list?

Comment: I know about canned responses, that's not what I need. I am mainly asking this question to see if I can work around writing a browser extension.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by directly clicking on the icon? You mean the icon in the card section or you want to bypass the usage of Card Service completely?

Answer (score 1):

To do this you have to understand how the click trigger the insertion of an image.

if you look at the tutorial you provided, there is a line responsible for the click action:

```
(...)            CardService.newImage()
                .setImageUrl(imageUrl)
                .setOnClickAction(CardService.newAction()
                      .setFunctionName('applyInsertImageAction')
                                  .setParameters({'url' : imageUrl})));
(...)
```

If we look into it a little closer we can see that we are telling our Images to have a `OnClickAction` that calls a new action with the function name of 'applyInsertImageAction' and the parameters `{"url":<imageUrl>}`.

So, in short, you have to call the `applyInsertImageAction` function with the correct parameters to execute this action without the need for the extra clicks on the images.

Hope this helps!